# Jquery Issue with click event bleed through

Tags: jquery, events, click, parent

I have a div that has a click event tied to it. I want to put an icon in that div that has it's own click event tied to it. When I click the icon, it fires the icon event and then fires the div's click event. How can I prevent the div's click event from firing?

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery's [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$('.element').click(function(e)) {
  // Do some processing

  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Stop the propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on the icon's click handler:

```
$(".myIcon").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // do stuff
});
```